# Are there STL functions to split/splice C-style arrays into smaller arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

Let's say I have a C-style array (int numbers[10]). I want to split the array into an array of odd numbers and an array of even numbers. Further, I'd like to use a predicate to determine if a number is odd.

**Question**: I am curious - are there STL functions that can do this?

The closest thing I can find is list::splice, but that's not for C-style arrays and doesn't take a predicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::partition()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) would work.

Indeed, Example 1 on that page is separating even and odd numbers. It's doing it on a vector, but there's no reason it wouldn't work on native arrays.

Here's a quick example I worked up:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    auto mid = std::partition(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
            [](int n){return n%2;});

    std::cout << "Odd: " << std::endl;
    for (auto p = std::begin(a); p < mid; ++p)
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Even: " << std::endl;
    for (auto p = mid; p < std::end(a); ++p)
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's say I want all evens in one C-style array and all odds in another. I presume just replace the cout's in the for loops with array insertions? Might there be a STL function that performs partition and returns a collection of arrays (so in this example, an array that points to the odd array and even array)?

Comment: @Craig: The return value of `std::partition()` is an iterator (which is, in the case of native arrays, a pointer) pointing to the the first item that did not match the predicate (the even numbers, in this case). It also serves as the "end" iterator for the items that did match. In most cases, you wouldn't need to copy or move them anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you can: [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) partitions a sequence according to a predicate.

```
auto begin = std::begin(array);
auto end   = std::end(array);
auto part  = std::partition(begin, end, [](int n){return n%2;});
```

Now `[begin,part)` contains the odd values (for which the predicate is true), and `[part,end)` contains the even values (for which the predicate is false).